# Identify line in hierarchical file bash script

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need to identify the head of a list of configuration entries in a file. There is not predictable, it could be any string, but it always be the line that starts closer to the left than the others (excluding "exit"):

Here is an example:

```
    vpls 2662 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2662 create
        description "RES_2662"
        mac-move
            allow-res-res
            allow-reg-res
        exit
        stp
            shutdown
        exit
        ingress
            qos 2
        exit
        sap lt:1/1/1:2662 create
            description "RES_2662"
            enable-stats
            no shutdown
        exit
        sap lag-1:2662 create
            no shutdown
        exit
        no shutdown
    exit
    vpls 2663 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2663 create
        description "RES_2663"
        mac-move
            allow-res-res
            allow-reg-res
        exit
        stp
            shutdown
        exit
        ingress
            qos 2
        exit
        sap lt:1/1/1:2663 create
            description "RES_2663"
            enable-stats
            no shutdown
        exit
        sap lag-1:2663 create
            no shutdown
```

In this case, I need to be able to identify the two lines that start with:
        `vpls 266X customer 1 v-vpls vlan 266X create`
The script should know that these are the lines that I'm looking for.

The output not always will show spaces at the left, like in this example:

```
port vlan-port:1/1/1/3/7/4/4:824
  admin-up
  severity no-value
exit
port vlan-port:1/1/1/3/7/4/4:1224
  admin-up
  severity no-value
exit
```

In this case, the desired lines are:
`port vlan-port:x/x/x/x/x/x/x/x`

I don't know if it can be done using grep/sed/awk.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and will retain the order of the input lines for the output in case that matters:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != "exit" {
    match($0,/^ */)
    if ( (min == "") || (RLENGTH <= min) ) {
        min = RLENGTH
        lines[min,++cnt[min]] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=cnt[min]; i++) {
        print lines[min,i]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
    vpls 2662 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2662 create
    vpls 2663 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2663 create
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are better ways of doing this, but my first thought was the following. You could possibly start with something like this and improve it.

```
minl=$(awk '{match($0, /^ */);if (NR==1 || RLENGTH<minl) {minl=RLENGTH}} END{print minl}' test.txt)
sed -n "/^[ ]\{${minl}\}[^ ]/p" test.txt | grep -v "exit"
```

The first line uses `awk` to get the get the minimum number of spaces at the front of a line for the file.

The second line uses `sed` to match lines starting with the number of spaces calculated in the first line. I piped the result of that through `grep -v "exit"` to get rid of the exit lines... you might need to do a stricter check if a valid line of output could contain the text "exit."

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution

```
# gets the number of leading spaces + 1
n=$(sort -r file.txt | sed -nE '1s/(^ *).*/\1/p' | wc -c | tr -d ' ')
# filter the file
egrep -vE "^ {$n,}|^ *exit" file.txt
```

Comment: It works well with the first example, but not with the second...

Comment: for me it produces `port vlan-port:1/1/1/3/7/4/4:824
port vlan-port:1/1/1/3/7/4/4:1224` which seems like the expected, what's your output?

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- leading white space is made up solely of spaces (ie, no tabs, no non-printing characters)

One `awk` idea where we maintain an array of those lines with the (current) minimum number of leading spaces, resetting the array whenever we find a row with fewer (ie, 'new' minimum) leading spaces:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { min = 9999999 }

/^$/    { exit }                  # skip blank lines

/exit/  { if {NF==1) next }       # skip lines with single field "exit"

        { n = match($0,/[^ ]/)    # find index of first non-space

          if ( n < min ) {        # if a new minimum is found then ...
             delete arr           # delete the array and ...
             i = 1                # reset the array index and ...
             min = n              # reset the min
          }

          if ( n == min )         # if current row matches with "min" then ...
             arr[i++] = $0        # save the row in our array; increment the index
        }

END     { for (j=1;j<i;j++)       # loop through entries in array
             print arr[j]
        }
' file.dat
```

For OP's 1st set of data this generates:

```
    vpls 2662 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2662 create
    vpls 2663 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2663 create
```

For OP's 2nd set of data this generates:

```
port vlan-port:1/1/1/3/7/4/4:824
port vlan-port:1/1/1/3/7/4/4:1224
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `perl` and `awk` combination:

```
$ perl -ne ' /(^.\s*)/ and !/^\s*exit/ and print length($1), $_ ' fernando.txt | sort -n | awk ' { f=$1; p=NR==1?f:p; sub(/^[0-9]+/,"",$0);if(f==p)  print } '
    vpls 2662 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2662 create
    vpls 2663 customer 1 v-vpls vlan 2663 create
```